# SVG Click event doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, events, svg, click, href

I've managed to be able to click on specific path in an svg with the "a" html tag. It works on Chrome and Edge, but in Firefox no click event is working.

Here's how I do it in my SVG:

```
 <a href='the_link' target='_parent'><rect x="205" y="478.4" class="st2 hover" width="112.5" height="36.6"/></a>
```

The "`<rect />`" is my svg path.

I was wondering if someone know what to do to make it work in firefox?

I don't know if could help finding the solution but here's my SVG header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

             viewBox="0 0 1254 650" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1254 650;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: use xlink:href rather than href

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!